# Как реализовать класс Point?

Tags: python, классы

Реализуйте класс Point (точка). У этого класса должны быть

- конструктор, принимающий два числа x и y, координаты точки на плоскости;
- атрибуты x и y через которые можно будет получить координаты точки;
- метод dist, который принимает еще один объект класса Point и находит эвклидово расстояние между двумя точками.

Импортировать ничего нельзя.

```
class Point(object):
    pass


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        
    p1 = Point()
    p2 = Point()
    x = input()
    y = input()

    def dist(self):
        dist = ((p1.x - p2.x) ^ 2 + (p1.y - p2.y) ^ 2) ** 0.5
        return p1.dist(p2)
```

Понимаю, что ошибка точно есть в использовании атрибутов, но как исправить не могу сообразить.

Comment: А у вас в коде такая же фигня с отступами как в вопросе?

Comment: Впервые пользовался этим сайтом, поэтому даже не заметил, что полетели отступы. Отныне буду проверять))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def dist(self, point):
        distance = ((self.x - point.x)**2 + (self.y - point.y)**2)**0.5
        return distance
```

по хорошему еще бы проверить, что `point` - это `Point` и выбросить исключение, если это не так

Comment: За `**2` спасибо :) Кст, насчет `Point` тут можно прямо не париться -- утиная типизацию, т.е. если у объекта есть `x` и `y`, то почему бы с ним не поработать :)

Comment: ну все таки хочется защиту какую-то иметь, а то мало ли что x и y означать могут :)

Comment: Тогда и `x` с `y ` нужно проверять, а то вдруг они будут, например, строками :D

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Отдельным местами у вас правильное направление мысли, но возникли проблемы с тем как всё собрать в одно.

Немного поколдовал над кодом, попробуйте:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dist(self, other):
        return ((self.x - other.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other.y) ** 2) ** 0.5


p1_x = int(input("p1.x: "))
p1_y = int(input("p1.y: "))

p2_x = int(input("p2.x: "))
p2_y = int(input("p2.y: "))

p1 = Point(p1_x, p1_y)
p2 = Point(p2_x, p2_y)

print(p1.dist(p2))
```

Comment: а вы тоже решили квадраты через ^ вычислять? :))))

Comment: @Zhihar, не смотрел на формулу автора :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я наконец-то разобрался)))

Comment: @Salva, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)